# Navigation Controller not inserting in some ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

[image]

I am trying to add navigation controller to all the viewcontrollers but when I try to do this using the Editor -> Embedded In -> Navigation Controller on the WelcomeViewController (Startup screen), the navigation controller is only added to login and register viewcontrollers and not the Chat viewcontroller. What is it that I'm doing wrong. **Maybe the type of segue I make affects how the navigation controller works.**
I would be helpful if I could find a way to fix this problem using the interface only because I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make `NavigationController` as initial controller.

**Please follow steps :**

1. Open storyboard
2. Select NavigationController.
3. Select "Is initial View Controller" in Attributes inspector.

Next : Please click on register button and drag onto `chatViewController`, You can see many option, please select **"Show"**

Hope its helpful to you...!!

Comment: Please try other way, in segue please select "show" option in chat controller.

Comment: Kindly elaborate where to find where to find show, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: In storyboard after on register and login button you want chat ViewController, Am i right?

Comment: So please click on register button and drag onto chat viewController, You can see many option, please select "Show".